# How to fill a rectangle knowing its vertices on 3D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry

I want to fill a rectangle area from a 3D matrix with specific values, but

I know only the 4 vertices of this rectangle.

What should I do?

Example:

```
Grid = zeros (10, 10, 3); 
% My vertices points
vx = [1 3 5 3]; 
vy = [3 5 3 1]; 
vz = [0 0 0 0]; 
% I want fill all the surface of rectangle 
% with the value [1 0 0] and the edges with [0.5 0.5 0]
```

Comment: I just removed my answer as I re-read your question and think I interpreted it incorrectly. Can you please be more clear, give an example of what you want? Do you want to plot this, replace a subset of a matrix, something else?

Comment: It depends which points you know. You can define a "rectangle" (subset of the 3D matrix?) with only 2 points, if they are the right ones

Comment: @Wolfie
For example I have 
Grid = zeros (10, 10, 3);
% My vertices
vx = [1 3 5 3];
vy = [3 5 3 1];
vz = [0 0 0 0];
I want fill all the surface of rectangle with the value [1 0 0]
and the edges with [0.5 0.5 0]

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have a kind of RGB image (a 3D matrix in my case)
so, I want to select and fill a specific zone of the image (a rectangle) with specific values (ex: [0.2 0.5 0.3])
But the problem that I Know only the vertices of this rectangle. 
Therefor I need an Algorithm the get the points in the surface of this rectangle!

Comment: This is confusing: what surface? What algorithm.  Do you just want `img(p1x:p2x,p1y,p2y,1)=0.2;img(p1x:p2x,p1y,p2y,2)=0.5;img(p1x:p2x,p1y,p2y,3)=0.3;`? There are no algorithm not surfaces not 3d rectangles

Comment: @AnderBiguri
This the right example that explains my need
but can't use patch function on my matrix !
     vx = [1 3 5 3];
     vy = [3 5 3 1];
     vz = [0 0 0 0];
     c = [1 0 0];
     figure
     patch(vy,vx,vz,c);
     colorbar

Comment: Please read [ask], you are being very unclear.

Comment: @AnderBiguri
my question in other form
In a 2D image
How can I get all the coordinates of points on the area of a rectangle by knowing only the vertices of this rectangle.

Comment: @A.AliHADID if you repeat the same words again they do not become more clear. Please take your time to explain what you want

Comment: Providing us a small example and the desired output may make things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem with **insertShape** function
https://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html

Example:

```
Grid = zeros (10, 10, 3); 
% The coordinates of vertices
vx = [1 3 5 3]; 
vy = [3 5 3 1]; 
values = [0.3 0.5 0.2];
Grid = insertShape(Grid ,'FilledPolygon', [ vx(1) vy(1), vx(2) vy(2), ... 
vx(3) vy(3) ,vx(4) vy(4)], 'Color' , values );
```